# HAProxy no stats from terminal

Tags: haproxy, source, centos6.4

I have haproxy installed on CentOs6.4 x64  but I need to see the stats from the terminal with command `haproxy -s`

The man file says

```
  -s     Show statistics (only if compiled in).  Statistics are only available if compiled in with the  'STATTIME'  option.   It's  only
         used during code optimization phases, and will soon disappear.
```

removed the current version with yum and compiled the source code with

```
make TARGET=linux2628 USE_EPOLL=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 STATTIME=1 ARCH=x86_64 && make install
```

everything works fine and the HAProxy is working but the `-s` option still not working

any ideas why this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

This option is designed to be used when you launch haproxy, not after its already running. If you want to use it you have to kill any running haproxy instances, then launch it manually with the -s option and any other parameters needed to launch it.

However, you should not be using this option to watch the statistics generated by haproxy. You should instead be looking at the stats webpage or the socket statistics interface, both of which have examples in the manual.